# Xcode (IOS) button press and release detection

Tags: ios, c, xcode

I have a UIView object that is hidden from start, and then when a Round Rect Button is pressed, the UIView object appears. So that all works well.

What I want is, whenever the Round Rect Button is released, the UIView object hides itself again.

Comment: Hello, your button is released by autorelease? Or you manually release it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A UIButton is a subclass of [UIControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl) and can respond to a number of Touch events.

You can specify which touch events the button instance responds to through creating IBActions in the storyboard or through code. The easiest way is through using the Storyboard.

[image]

So to achieve what you describe, you would have (at least) two IBActions - one for the 'touch down' event and one for the 'touch up' event. You should also handle other event cases like 'touch canceled', etc.

**Kinds of events possible for control objects.**

```
enum {
   UIControlEventTouchDown           = 1 <<  0,
   UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat     = 1 <<  1,
   UIControlEventTouchDragInside     = 1 <<  2,
   UIControlEventTouchDragOutside    = 1 <<  3,
   UIControlEventTouchDragEnter      = 1 <<  4,
   UIControlEventTouchDragExit       = 1 <<  5,
   UIControlEventTouchUpInside       = 1 <<  6,
   UIControlEventTouchUpOutside      = 1 <<  7,
   UIControlEventTouchCancel         = 1 <<  8,

   UIControlEventValueChanged        = 1 << 12,

   UIControlEventEditingDidBegin     = 1 << 16,
   UIControlEventEditingChanged      = 1 << 17,
   UIControlEventEditingDidEnd       = 1 << 18,
   UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit = 1 << 19,

   UIControlEventAllTouchEvents      = 0x00000FFF,
   UIControlEventAllEditingEvents    = 0x000F0000,
   UIControlEventApplicationReserved = 0x0F000000,
   UIControlEventSystemReserved      = 0xF0000000,
   UIControlEventAllEvents           = 0xFFFFFFFF
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the code in button's action

```
[view setHidden:!view.isHidden];
```